# Updating values within arrays in MongoDB/Mongoose within multiple documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection with objects in nested arrays. I'd like to be able to loop through each document and update any objects within the arrays with certain reference. For example:

```
{
    level: 3
    framework: 'England',
    units: [{
        number: 3.01,
        name: 'Introduction',
        fileName: '3.01.pdf' 
    }]
},

{
    level: 3,
    framework: 'Scotland',
    units: [
    {
        number: 3.01,
        name: 'Introduction',
        fileName: '3.01.pdf' 
    },
    {
        number: 3.03,
        name: 'Intermediate',
        fileName: '3.03.pdf'
    }]
},
{
    level: 4
    framework: 'England',
    units: [{
        number: 4.01,
        name: 'Higher Introduction',
        fileName: '4.01.pdf' 
    }]
}
```

How do I update the fileName for any item in any of the `units` arrays with a `number` of `3.01`. Everything I've managed to find so far has only been about how to update a single document, not all matching entries within all documents.

Thanks!

Comment: You did half of the job already. Iterate the collection of matching documents, update `units` array with plain js, and save the document.

Answer (score 0):

The key to updating the array elements field is to create a separate dataset with the matching documents, loop through them and update your collection using the **[`Bulk API`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** which allows you to send many update operations within a single request (as a batch).

The best option of creating the separate dataset would be to use the aggregation framework where you can aggregate all the documents in the collection to return the above dataset for processing.

---

Let's see with some examples how this pens out:

*a) For MongoDB server version 3.2 and above*

```
var operations = [];
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "units.number": 3.01 } },
    { 
        "$project": {
            "units": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$units",
                    "as": "unit",
                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$unit.number", 3.01 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).forEach(function(doc){
    doc.units.forEach(function(unit){
        operations.push({
            "updateOne": {
                "filter": { 
                    "_id": doc._id,
                    "units.fileName": unit.fileName
                },
                "update": {
                    "$set": { "units.$.fileName": "updated_3.01.pdf" }
                }
            }
        });

        // Send once in 500 requests only
        if (operations.length % 1000 === 0 ) {
            db.collection.bulkWrite(operations);
            operations = [];
        }
    });
})

// Clear remaining queue
if (operations.length > 0 )
    db.collection.bulkWrite(operations);
```

In the above, you initialise your operations array which would be used by the Bulk API's **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)** function and holds the update operations. The preceding **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** operation will act as a filter to documents which need to be updated and allows you to create a unique identifier for the array element to be updated which makes it easier to use the **[`$ positional operator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** in the update.

The result from the aggregate operation is then iterated to create the operations array with the update objects. The operations are limited to
batches of 500. The reason of choosing a lower value than the default batch limit of 1000 is generally a controlled choice. As noted in the documentation there, MongoDB by default will send to the s[erver in batches of 1000 operations at a time at maximum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Operation-Limit-Size) and there is no guarantee that makes sure that these default 1000 operations requests actually fit under the [16MB BSON limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size). So you would still need to be on the "safe" side and impose a lower batch size that you can only effectively manage so that it totals less than the data limit in size when sending to the server.

---

*a) If using MongoDB v3.0 or below:*

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "units.number": 3.01 } },
    { 
        "$project": {
            "units": {
                "$setDifference": [
                   { 
                       "$map": {
                           "input": "$units",
                           "as": "unit",
                           "in": {
                               "$cond": [
                                   { "$eq": [ "$$unit.number", 3.01 ] },
                                   "$$unit",
                                   false
                               ]
                           }
                       }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.units.forEach(function(unit) {
        bulk.find({ 
            "_id": doc._id, 
            "units.fileName": unit.fileName  
        }).updateOne({
            "$set": { "units.$.fileName": "updated_3.01.pdf" }
        });
        counter++;

        if (counter % 500 === 0) {
            bulk.execute();
            bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        }
    });
});

if (counter % 500 !== 0)
    bulk.execute();
```